# Should each component have its own mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

If many components share the same actions, is it better to create a single `mapDispatchToProps` function that can be passed to `connect()` for each component, or to define a separate one for each?

I have two components that share 10 actions, but one of them needs an extra action that is not relevant to the other. It seems overkill to redefine the entire `mapDispatchToProps` for the sake of a single action, but it's not cohesive to just tack it on.

Answer (score 0):

Create another component which has all the shared actions in it, with a map dispatch to props, and then create another component from this base component. You can add/modify the base components action and functionalities afterwards. for example:

```
export class BaseComp extends Component {
  action1() {
  //some action
  }
  action2() {
  //some action
  }
}
```

now if you want u can use this all by itself, but in the case you want to add some other functionalities you can do something like this:

```
export class secondComp extends BaseComp {
  action3(){
  //some action
  }
}
```

just put your map dispatch to props in the first component and the second one will inherit it or for the case of new functionalities and actions you might need to add just one more `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: how do you call action1 and action2 from secondComp? `this.action1` is undefined